# Elasticsearch not returning all matched products

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I have enabled Elasticsearch for my store in Magento 2.2.4.

When searching for a particular product with Elasticsearch enabled, 20 products are returned. When I turn off Elasticsearch and switch back to the standard MySQL search, 55 results are returned. This pattern is mirrored throughout the entire product catalog, regardless of the particular product in question.

Furthermore my live installation also returns different results to my local installation even though the same database is being used.

I wonder if anyone has experienced this kind of pattern when using Elasticsearch and has any idea what could be possible cause of this.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Any update on this?

Comment: Depends on what Pattern Matching criteria you have setup.  Elastic searching does not rely on the standard search system 
EDIT - There is some further reading in this amasty blog post https://amasty.com/blog/elasticsearch-by-magento-and-amasty/